# Best Prototype Resolution for Public Sector

Tags: prototype, screen-resolution

I'm frequently designing web application prototypes with Axure RP 10 for the public sector. Usually, I use the resolution of 1920x1080 px with the smallest font in 24 px(next bigger header is preceding size * 1,3).

Since I assume that some people working in the public sector don't have the same big designer screens a I do, should I shift my prototypes to a 1440 x 900 py resolutions with a 18px font?

Comment: I am in a NYC civil service agency, and we no longer use screens of lower resolution than 1920x1080. I'm not even sure that you can get screens with lower resolutions any longer.